# How to get access to redux props wit condtional rendering

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using redux to fetch my data from my component, at this time all was work fine, but now I need to use conditional rendering so I create a new function`Interactions` that will fetch the data and filter and all this, but I am getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined` but if I take my `this.props.feeds` outside my function that is working well, so the question is how can I have access to my redux props inside my Interactions function ?

```
class Feed extends React.Component {

componentDidMount() {

    this.props.fetchActivityFeed();
}

render() {

    console.log(this.props.feeds) // this is working

    function Interactions() { 
         //Getting error here
        this.props.feeds.filter(({type}) => type === 
        'Interaction').map(( activity, i) => {
                return(<p> {activity.description}</p>);
            }
        )
    }

    const panes = [
        {
            menuItem: 'All',
            render: () => <Tab.Pane  attached={false}>  /* Here I need 
            to render my Component <Interactions/>*/ </Tab.Pane>,
        },
        {
            menuItem: 'Interactions',
            render: () => <Tab.Pane attached={false}> <Interactions/> 
        </Tab.Pane>,
        },
        {
            menuItem: 'Tasks',
            render: () => <Tab.Pane attached={false}>Tab 3 Content</Tab.Pane>,
        },
        {
            menuItem: 'Expenses',
            render: () => <Tab.Pane attached={false}>Tab 3 Content</Tab.Pane>,
        },
    ];
    return (
        <div> <Interactions /> </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    feeds: state.ActivityFeedReducer
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchActivityFeed})(Feed);
```

PS : I need to have a Component to render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a component (`<Interactions />`) inside another component (`<Feed />`), and you are not passing the second one any props. You have a scope problem here.

Here is what I would do to fix this. File separation like so:

Feed component:

```
class Feed extends React.Component {

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchActivityFeed();
}

render() {
    return (
        <div> 
          <Interactions feeds={this.props.feeds} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Interactions component:

```
function Interactions({feeds}) { 
  return (
    <div>
      {feeds && feeds.filter(({type}) => type === 
        'Interaction').map(( activity, i) =>
            <p>{activity.description}</p>)
        )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Maybe do you have another way to do that without creating new files because all my new components will be a tab

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM**: You are using 'this' inside a functional, which refers to the function itself that is, the function Interactions.

**SOLUTION**: Drop that additional functional component that you are creating, rather use the props in the class component Feed, and return it from there.

try this.

```
class Feed extends React.Component {

componentDidMount() {

    this.props.fetchActivityFeed();
}

render() {
    return (
            this.props && this.props.feeds && this.props.feeds.filter(({type}) => type === 'Interaction').map(( activity, i) => {
            return(<p> {activity.description}</p>);
        }
        )
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    feeds: state.ActivityFeedReducer
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchActivityFeed})(Feed);
```

Comment: I need to have a component to render, i edited my post